# No performance gain with python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, web-crawler

I'm writing a parallel crawler using Python and I'm storing some information in Mongodb. After testing I realized that my code, even though is using threading, is not parallel. It make no difference whether I use a single thread or 10 or 50 threads. I can't figure out why.

EDIT: From what I can see most of the processing time is taken up by `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`. Could it be that this command can't get parallelized using threads?

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue
import urllib2
import re
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urlparse import urljoin
from pymongo import MongoClient
from urlparse import urlparse
import time
import hashlib

start_time = time.time()

level = 1
client = MongoClient()
db = client.crawler
visited = {}

def doWork():
    while True:
        try:
            myUrl = q_start.get()
        except:
            continue
        try:
            c=urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)
        except:
            q_start.task_done()
            continue

        parsed_url = urlparse(myUrl)

        html=c.read()
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        except:
            q_start.task_done()

            continue
        txt = soup.prettify()
        links = soup('a')
        m = hashlib.md5(myUrl)

        db.urls.insert(
                {
                    "url":myUrl,
                    "HTML":txt,
                    "level":level,
                    "domain":parsed_url.netloc,
                    "md5":m.hexdigest()
                }
        )

        for link in links:

            if('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
                url = urljoin(myUrl,link['href'])
                if url.find("'")!=-1:
                    continue
                url=url.split('#')[0]
                if url[0:4] == 'http':
                    if url in visited:
                        continue
                    else:
                        visited[url]=True
                        q_new.put(url)
        q_start.task_done() 

q_start = Queue.Queue()

q_new = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(50):
        t = Thread(target=doWork)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

q_start.put("http://google.com")
q_start.join()

for i in range(2,5):
    print "Depth: "
    print i
    print time.time() - start_time
    level += 1
    print q_new.qsize()
    q_aux = q_new
    q_new = Queue.Queue()
    while q_aux.empty() != True:
        x = q_aux.get()
        q_start.put(x)
    q_start.join()

print "end"

print time.time() - start_time
```

Comment: There probably is no difference because network is the bottleneck.

Comment: @Tichodroma I think the general "principle" here ( if not the implementation ) is that if you can execute "parallel" operations in different "threads/event ticks" then with "waiting" overhead of network operations is generally mitigated ( except in total ). So essentially the difference between executing 100 operations "sequentially" or submitting 100 operations "all at once" and then "collecting" the responses. That's the basic intro to how we do "high performance" programming.